# How to determine if there is date in a string with XSL 1.0

Tags: xslt

I have a string "text text text 21.04.15 - 24.04.15 12345678".
I want to know if there is a date in this string that fits pattern xx.xx.xx - xx.xx.xx.

I understand xsl 1.0 doesnt support regex. How can i do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Which XSLT 1.0 processor on which platform do you use? An XSLT 1.0 processor in .NET like `XslCompiledTransform` can call .NET functions for instance, an XSLT 1.0 processor in Java can call into Java. MSXML can call Javascript or VBScript. So depending on the XSLT processor you might be able to easily delegate the date or regular expression test to another language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
contains(translate($string,'123456789', '000000000'), '00.00.00')
```

Note that this may return false positives, for example if the string contains "123.45.3789". With some effort, you could eliminate these by including the surrounding punctuation (assuming you know all possible punctuation characters that could appear in the given text).

Note also that no testing is performed to make sure the pattern represents a a valid date.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

XSL 1.0 is very old. Why can't you use XSL 2.0?

Using regular expressions:

`\s+(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2})\s+\-\s+(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2})\s+`

https://regex101.com/r/mW1sK2/2

Here's an article explaining XSL 2.0 regex from 2003:
http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/06/04/tr.html

Comment: I`m working with a system that is using XSL 1.0. We havent yet migrated to XSL 2.0.

Comment: Just be aware that some people who answer questions on these forums are quite happy for you to waste your own time by using an ancient language, but they find it frustrating when you also want to waste theirs.